# Excel: keyboard shortcut to move (swap) column left or right?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to move a column (or row) to the left using only the keyboard?
I known I can use ctrl-space (shift-space) to select a column (row), but how to move it to the left or right, actually swapping position with the column to its left or right?

(I am using Excel 2007)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're not set on using the keyboard only, highlight the column, either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or clicking on the column header. Then press and hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. In some environments you may see the selection box (border) around the column change to an I-bar. Then you can drag the column to the left or right (using the mouse) and it will *move* the column there without overwriting data or leaving a blank column.

This also works with rows, and with ranges of columns or rows. The I-bar changes to horizontal or vertical as you move the range, and separates the columns or rows where it will move the range to.

To summarize:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to select the source column(s).
- Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you drag the column(s).

Comment: And if you use (Ctrl)+(Shift) while you drag, it will create new column(s) or row(s) and _copy_ the data there, much like (Ctrl)+drag in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Nice! I've accepted your answer even though it requires brief usage of the mouse. 
As it might not be obvious to everyone: dragging the column is done by first hovering over the column borders (cursor changes into 4-arrows symbol) before pressing the left mouse button.

Comment: I was really hoping there would be and easy way to do that like `Alt` + `Up Arrow` and `Alt` + `Down Arrow` in Visual Studio. Oh well.

Comment: The author of question asks how to MOVE a column using the keyboard only, but not how to select it for further moving with the mouse.

Answer (score 20):

Best I can come up with is something like this (note, this works in Excel 2003 - might not work in 07/10, but you've haven't indicated which version you are using):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the source col.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to cut the col.

<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move to the column you want to move the selected column to the left of.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to select the target col.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to insert the cut cells (with thanks to **variant** for that useful comment!).

I'm thinking that [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or a short macro might be a good way to achieve this.
It should be easy to record a quick Excel macro using the above set of commands, just make sure "Relative Reference" is on.

Comment: Yep, that works (even in Excel 2007), bit long-winded though :-)

Comment: Indeed, if you wish to use it a lot then record it as a macro and assign it a keyboard shortcut. Or try using AutoHotkey to automate it without having to add macros to your files.

Comment: Instead of Alt+I then E, you can simply hit Ctrl + +. This will insert just the same.

Comment: If you are in Excel 2007 / 2010 and are trying to move a column in a `table` be sure to select from the `header` cell with `Ctrl` + `Space` in the desired column and not just any cell in the column. Otherwise you'll get the error `This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet.`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Excel keyboard shortcuts list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP005203781.aspx), there is no built-in shortcut to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To move a single cell or row or column do the following:

- Select the cell(s)
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Move to the new location
- Do one of the following:

  - Type <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or
  - Press the <kbd>≣ (Menu)</kbd> key (which may be between the <kbd>Windows</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys on some keyboards, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> if the key is not available),
    and select "Insert Cut Cells".

The cells will be inserted to the left or above the selection.

Comment: Is this any different from Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V?

Comment: @Noumenon Yes, Ctrl+V will overwrite the selected cells , while _Insert Cut Cells_ will insert the cut cells **between** the current location and the column to the left (or row above), shifting the current location to the right (or down).

Answer (score 2):

An important difference between inserting a blank column and pasting into it, vs. "insert cut cells" is that the later will shift your other columns to the right, but NOT their column width formatting.  So if you 'insert cut cells,' all the columns to the right will have the widths of the their former columns one to the right and you will have to readjust them to fit your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Double-click on the column you would like to move (it will highlight the whole column)
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> at the same time (you will see the selection cut)
- Hit the arrow key to move in whichever direction you want to move (LEFT arrow Or Right Arrow)
- Point between the columns, and release the mouse
- Where you point after the next right column will be deleted automatically (careful: select one Blank column, then move the column )

Example: If you moving a column Between A & B, it is possible that B will be remove) so before moving any column, bring up an empty column between two columns and after you start moving the column.

In summary, select the column (Double click), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, move with arrow left or right.

Comment: This was a bit difficult to follow, I tried my best with it, but you may want to clarify it some more.

Answer (score 0):

The method by Hemal (?) works, but **the trick is to create a new column** where you want to move to, Excel will leave a blank column behind where the data were previously to be used or deleted.

1. Double click when the down-pointing arrow appears above the column header for the data you want to move.
2. Hit Ctrl+x
3. Move with arrow keys to the location of the new column and hit Enter
4. Hit Enter

Data moved to the new column.

If you hit enter on a populated column, it is overwritten.  Not slick or "clean", but it's an easy shoehorn to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a particular row or column or cells you just need to select cells pressing Shift with Arrow key after selecting cells just press ctrl+shift+(+) and select the the option for moving down,up, right and left by arrow keys and press Enter. Done!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.