# Swap cell contents in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there an easy way to swap the contents of two cells in Microsoft Excel?

By easy, I mean either a keyboard shortcut or menu item, without involving copying to temporary cells or writing VBA scripts or anything like that. In other words, I'm looking for a way to just select two cells and click some menu item or press some key combination that will swap their contents. Surely, there has got to be a way to do this?

Comment: This seems like a very specific implementation of a sort, and if its not already present in the advanced sorting options, I'd be surprised if you can find it elsewhere, as a non-VBA solution

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/860-excel-swap-contents-of-two-cells.html

> Sometimes, there are two adjoining cells need to be swapped. We can manually do it easily. Look at the following screenshot, I want to swap cell A4 and B4, please do as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Select the cell you want to swap. In this example, select cell A4.
> 2. Press **Shift** key, and put the cursor at the right border.
> 3. Then drag the cursor to the right border of cell B4.
> 4. When there displays “工”, release the mouse.
> 5. And the two cell contents have been swapped.
>
> [image]
>
> With this method, we can also swap two adjoining rows or columns.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It just insert empty cells between those 2 cells

Comment: This only works for adjacent cells which is not what the original question asked for.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me on Excel 2010 - it quickly flashes, but the contents of the cells remain unchanged.

Comment: @phuclv I had the same issue as you before I realised that, for step 2, I was putting the mouse cursor on the bottom right border rather than the middle right border.

Comment: Note, works in the desktop app, but does not work in the online browser Excel (I.e. opened in OneDrive in browser)

Answer (score 27):

**For the specific case of adjacent same-size rectangular ranges**, you can use the method described in [this answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/178227/72707).

1. Select the right or bottom range
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
3. Select the adjacent range (i.e., directly above or to the left)
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>**+**</kbd> (the `+` is usually above the `=` key so this translates to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>)

Note you can use the same procedure to swap whole adjacent rows or columns.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Being able to use keyboard shortcuts and being able to operate on multiple cells is so much faster.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. And the cells are adjacent to each other. I don't know why this doesn't work. Is there any particular explanation for this command?

Comment: This is for me the correct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 15):

> By easy, I mean either a keyboard shortcut or menu item, without involving copying to temporary cells or **writing VBA scripts** or anything like that. I'm looking for a way to just select two cells and click some menu item or press some key combination that will swap their contents.

Why impose this restriction? Creating a macro makes this trivial. As far as I know, it can't be done any other way. You can assign the macro to a button or hotkey.

```vb
Sub Swap()     
    If Selection.Count <> 2 Then     
         MsgBox "Select 2 cells (only) to swap."     
         Exit Sub     
    End If     
    Set trange = Selection     
    If trange.Areas.Count = 2 Then     
         temp = trange.Areas(2)     
         trange.Areas(2) = trange.Areas(1)     
         trange.Areas(1) = temp     
    Else     
         temp = trange(1)     
         trange(1) = trange(2)     
         trange(2) = temp     
    End If     
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not a VBA expert and have neither the time nor the inclination to become one. I also frequently use many different computers. It would be nice to have swapping available on every computer I use for Excel, without having to look-up the code for the VBA macro that does it, so that I can bind it to a hotkey.

Comment: @Dan It would be nice if everyone could have their pet functionality built into Excel, but then it would become even more a bloated mess than it already is. There is a reason why Excel has a macro language, to automate repetitive tasks like this. I posted code found through a google search. You don't *have* to be an expert.

Comment: +1 vba is the way excel allows you to add your pet functions.  there are also ways of making that vba avaliable on many computers, to just yourself or to all (eg personal workbook, or addins)

Comment: I would hardly call swapping the content of two cells / rows /columns to be a pet function.

Comment: @Nicolai One person's essential feature is another person's pet function. If it's not a "pet function" please let me know what spreadsheet software has the capability built in. I'm genuinely interested to know why you view such a feature as essential.

Comment: @ghoppe Maybe not essential, but if you do a quick search on "swap the content of two cells in excel" (which you already have) it is quite obvious that Dan and I are hardly the only ones that care about this feature.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no way to swap the contents of two cells in Excel, without writing your own macro to do it.

EDIT: It sounds like there may now be an easy way to swap cell contents in more recent versions of Excel, so this answer is probably now out of date.

Comment: this statement is incorrect. See the answer from user190216.

Comment: @KarlRookey Originally that answer stated (and it kind of still does) that the cells must be adjacent. It sounds like this may no longer be true for more recent versions of Excel. If that's the case, then, yes, there is now a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for saying this.  All the examples here have a *side effect* of swapping two cells (if they are adjacent) but doesn't "swap cells", it "shifts" cells.

Answer (score 2):

Select first set of cells to be swapped and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>:

Select the cells BESIDE the ones you want to swap with and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: This works only if cells are adjacent. Otherwise the whole stuff is shifted near target cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste up to 25 items to the clipboard, so they are easy to swap using ctr+tab or cmd+tab mac

Comment: Is this a standard Mac feature?  The author of the question didn't specify what platform they are on.  I'm not sure whether the standard clipboard in all versions of Windows holds more than one item, but free utilities are readily available to provide that functionality (and the keyboard shortcuts may vary).  Could you expand your answer to make it more comprehensive for this approach?

Comment: I tried this on Windows but couldn't figure it out. I even tried the ctrl+shift+p option that normally works in Visual Studio to paste out of the clipboard ring.

Answer (score 0):

I read this post but actually needed a macro to swap full ranges. In addition, I needed to swap the colors. Modded the originally posted macro slightly, this might be useful for someone.

```vb
Sub Swap()

    If Selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then
         MsgBox "Select 2 cell ranges (only) to swap."
         Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    If Selection.Areas(1).Count <> Selection.Areas(2).Count Then
         MsgBox "The two areas must be of equal size"
         Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'With this for loop we run through each cell 1 by 1
    For i = 1 To Selection.Areas(1).Count
        'Swapping values
        temp = Selection.Areas(1)(i)
        Selection.Areas(1)(i) = Selection.Areas(2)(i)
        Selection.Areas(2)(i) = temp
        
        'Swapping color
        tempColor = Selection.Areas(1)(i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
        Selection.Areas(1)(i).Interior.ColorIndex = Selection.Areas(2)(i).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
        Selection.Areas(2)(i).Interior.ColorIndex = tempColor
    Next i
    
End Sub
```